# JavaScript-Load-Image afte Crop add to jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

[JavaScript Load Image Demo](http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/)
Can I add result from crop to file upload ?  [jQuery File Upload Demo](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

```
 file.canvas = $j('#result canvas');
 file.type = 'blob';

 $('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: file});
```

Not work

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: $j('#result a').attr('href')});
```

Not work